# I am trying to write a function which takes in a string as a parameter, and changes the case of each letter at every odd index in the string

Tags: python

It should leave all punctuation and numbers unchanged.
This is what I have written so far:

```
def mock(string):
    s = ""
    index = 0
    for character in string:
        if index % 2 == 0:
            if character.islower():
                s += character.upper()
                index += 1
            elif character.isupper():
                s += character.lower()
                index += 1
            elif ord(character) >= 33 and ord(character) <= 47 or ord(character) == 32:
                s += character
                index += 1
        index += 1
    return s
print(mock("Abcd. Efgh.. Ijkl!"))
```

The function should return "abCd. efGh.. IJkL!". However, my output gives me "aBCD. eFGH.. iJKL!". How can I fix my code to so that my program works properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `swapcase` and `join`:

```py
def mock(s):
    return ''.join(x if i % 2 else x.swapcase() for i, x in enumerate(s))

print(mock("Abcd. Efgh.. Ijkl!")) # abCd. efGh.. IJkL!
```

To (minimally) correct your code, try:

```py
def mock(string):
    s = ""
    index = 0
    for character in string:
        if index % 2 == 0:
            if character.islower():
                s += character.upper()
                index += 1
            elif character.isupper():
                s += character.lower()
                index += 1
            elif ord(character) >= 33 and ord(character) <= 47 or ord(character) == 32:
                s += character
                index += 1
        else: # this part is corrected
            s += character
            index += 1
    return s
```

In your original code, `index` is not increased correctly; for example, if `index % 2 == 0` is `True`, then `index` is incremented once in the `if` clause, and then *once again* outside the `if` clause.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using swapcase and enumerate? I am taking an introductory python class and have not learned about those.

Comment: @HitanshuJani See the updated part.

Comment: Ahh I see! I understand what I was doing wrong. I just updated my index values and everything worked just fine. Thank you!